# Web service from WSDL

Tags: java, web-services

I want to generate service implementation from WSDL (Top down approach) in Java but I dont want to use any tool. For example If we want to create stubs we can use wsimport.

Please let me know if this is a duplicate question.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure, that you really don't want to use existing tools for generating web services from WSDL? That means a lot of work, which could be done in a seconds with help of IDE(Eclipse or Idea) or wsdl2java tool for example.

Comment: I know that from Eclipse we can do that easily but I want to do that in IntelliJ if there is any way.

Comment: Not sure, if it could be done without some plugins. There is one I know about, but not sure, is it supported now, because it's not a new one https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/tools/idea/Idea_plug-in_userguide.html

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use any tool to generate code or stubs, maybe you would like to use Spring WebServices. This way you only create an **EndPoint** able to process WS messages, that is, you only worry about implementing server logic.

With this approach you can define beans to marshalling, using jaxb2 (or another), and the **EndPoint** brings you functionality to receive not XML payload, but Java Objects instead.

If you don't want to genereta code or stubs, I think Spring WS is nice for you.

If you don't want to use any tool at all, then sorry for my answer, but I believed what you didn't want is to generate code.

Comment: Thanks for replying...i want to generate code...to you my question is suppose if I generate client through wsimport and I provide impl file. Can both be used as service?

Comment: Sorry not sure. I don't use wsimport. If that serve for you I used ws services implemented with wsimport using SpringWS without considering wsimport implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the Maven plugins which create Java from WSDL:

**Axis :**

[Axis plugin](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html)

**CXF**

[CXF plugin](https://axis.apache.org/axis/java/maven/wsdl2java/)

Comment: Thanks for replying but I am looking for revers, WSDL to java also not the client...I want service